# Pass php variables to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am new to MySQL and PHP.  I have spent several hours on my .html page and my .php page. I am using XAMPP and PhpStorm.  When I enter my data, I get a "Failure" result.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.
NOTE: I know I should be using POST rather than GET.

```
<?php
//Variables from EditUser.html
$FName = $_GET['FName'];
$LName = $_GET['LName'];
$UName = $_GET['UName'];
$Pass = $_GET['password'];
$Role = $_GET['Role'];

print_r($_GET);

$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$password="";
$database="techinfo";

$connect = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database);
if(!$connect){die("Connection Failed");}
$sql = "INSERT INTO techinfo.techs (DBFN, LName, Username, password, Role)
        VALUES ('$FName', '$LName','$UName','$Pass','$Role'))";
if(mysqli_query($connect,$sql)){echo "New record created";}
else{echo "Failure";}
mysqli_close($connect);
?>
```

Comment: Instead of `echo "Failure"` use the error reporting function, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php. You also are open to SQL injections and should be hashing your users passwords.

Comment: write (echo mysqli_error($connect);)

Comment: Many thanks... a misplaced ')' was all it was.